# Doctrine update not using discriminator on Single Table Inheritance

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I am implementing inheritance in a project using single table stategy.

Everything seems to work fine on selection. But when it comes to update I am facing an issue.

Deck:

```
<?php
//src/Deck.php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="DeckRepository")
 * @Table(name="deck")
 **/
class Deck
{
    /** @id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Mainboard", mappedBy="deck")
     * @var Mainboard[]
     **/
    protected $mainboard = null;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Sideboard", mappedBy="deck")
     * @var Sideboard[]
     **/
    protected $sideboard = null;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Maybeboard", mappedBy="deck")
     * @var Maybeboard[]
     **/
    protected $maybeboard = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->createdon = new Datetime();
        $this->mainboard = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->sideboard = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->maybeboard = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    [getters and setter]
?>
```

DeckEntry:

```
<?php
//src/DeckEntry.php

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="deck_card")
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @id @DiscriminatorColumn(name="board", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"1" = "Mainboard", "2" = "Sideboard", "3" = "Maybeboard"})
 **/
abstract class DeckEntry
{
    /**
     * @id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Deck") @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $deck;

    /**
     * @id @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Card") @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="multiverseid")
     **/
    protected $card;

    /** 
     * @Column(type="integer")
     **/
    protected $quantity;

    [getters/setters]
?>
```

Mainboard/Sideboard/Maybeboard:

```
<?php
//src/[Mainboard/Sideboard/Maybeboard].php

/**
 * @Entity
 */
final class [Mainboard/Sideboard/Maybeboard] extends DeckEntry
{
}
?>
```

When I update a DeckEntry instance all DeckEntry instances sharing the same Deck and Card get updated whichever board they belong to.

Here's my update code:

```
switch ($_POST['board']) {
    case 'mainboard' :
        $deckEntry = $entityManager->getRepository('Mainboard')->find(array(
            'deck' => $_POST['deck_id'],
            'card' => $_POST['card_id']));
        break;
    case 'sideboard' :
        $deckEntry = $entityManager->getRepository('Sideboard')->find(array(
            'deck' => $_POST['deck_id'],
            'card' => $_POST['card_id']));
        break;
    case 'maybeboard' :
        $deckEntry = $entityManager->getRepository('Maybeboard')->find(array(
            'deck' => $_POST['deck_id'],
            'card' => $_POST['card_id']));
        break;
}
$deckEntry->setQuantity($_POST['up_inv_qty']);
$entityManager->persist($deckEntry);
```

This code generates the following select and update statements:

```
    Query SELECT t0.quantity AS quantity1, t0.deck_id AS deck_id2, t0.card_id AS card_id3, t0.board FROM deck_card t0 WHERE t0.deck_id = '2' AND t0.card_id = '370772' AND t0.board IN ('1')
    Query UPDATE deck_card SET quantity = '1' WHERE deck_id = '2' AND card_id = '370772'
```

I can't figure out why the discriminant field is missing from the update statement thus updating all DeckEntries with matching Deck and Card. This also occurs when adding a new DeckEntry for an existing combination of Deck and Card in a different board.

Any help is greatly appreciated!